# A Turing machine for which it is impossible to predict whether it halts or not on a fixed input

Tags: turing-machines, computability, undecidability, halting-problem

The halting problem is undecidable, i.e. $\not \exists$ $M$ Turing machine s.t. for every $(M_0,w_0)$ input where $M$ is the description of a Turing machine and $w_0$ is an input word, the output of $M$ is "$1$" if $M_0$ will halt on $w_0$ and "$0$" if it will not.

From this statement only, it does not follow that there must be an ($M_0,w_0$) pair for which it is impossible to predict if $M_0(w_0)$ halts or not. It only means there is no general way to decide this question for all ($M_0,w_0$) pairs.

So my question is the following: Does there exist a ($M_0,w_0$) pair for which it is known that it is impossible to predict whether $M_0(w_0$) halts or not? If yes, is there a known example or construction for an ($M_0,w_0$) pair such that?

Comment: @Steven has given an answer in the comments [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/123536/constructing-a-turing-machine-which-decides-whether-a-fixed-tm-will-halt-on-a-fi/123538?noredirect=1#comment258712_123538) as a pure existence proof so I would be more interested in a construction if possible but any idea or answer would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "impossible to predict"?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I mean that observing only the description of $M_0$ and the input word $w_0$, it cannot be concluded whether $M_0$ will halt on $w_0$ or not. 

I.e., there is no program or algorithm which examines $M_0$ and $w_0$, computes anything it wants, runs without any time and space constraints etc., but it stops in finite time with output "$1$" if $M_0(w_0)$ halts and "$0$" otherwise.
This program doesn't have to run correctly on any other ($M, w$) pair but must give correct output for ($M_0, w_0$).

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I know that for any ($M_0, w_0$) either a program which always says "$1$" or another one which always says "$0$" will be good. My question is: can we always decide for a fixed ($M_0, w_0$) which one runs correctly?

Comment: This doesn’t help at all. It only pushes the problem to a different phrase: what do you mean by “can we always decide”? Who should decide, and how?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Say a program with finite running time and without any other constraints.

For other $(M, w)$ pairs, other programs can be allowed.

Comment: In your comment you already mentioned that a program can always decide a specific, hardcoded case.

Comment: Here is one suggestion: you want an example of a Turing machine for which it cannot be proved (in some fixed proof system) that the machine halts, and also it cannot be proved that the machine doesn’t halt.

Comment: In this case, you can take the Turing machine which goes over all proofs in the proof system, looking for a proof of contradiction. Godel’s theorem shows that the theory cannot that this never halts, although “we” know it to be the case (everything, assuming the proof system is sound).

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I meant a program with finite running time and without any other constraints should decide whether the program which always says "$1$" or the other one which always says "$0$" gives the proper answer for our fixed $M_0$ and $w_0$. 

This "decider program" can differ for other $(M, w)$ pairs. Is it true that there is a such decider for every fixed $(M_0, w_0)$?

Comment: I don’t think we’re making any progress here.

Comment: The halting problem says no *one* machine can decide weather *every* given input pair halts or not. It seem's you're asking is there *one* input for which no machine, when run on that input, halts and accepts IFF the input pair halts. There is no such input for a trivial reason. A given input pair either halts or loops. If it halts the machine that accepts all inputs "makes the correct prediction" (if you can call it that). If it loops the machine that always rejects suffices..

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: I think it would be worth writing an answer in which you make the two points you made in the comments, namely that (1) for any specific machine $M$ and input $w$ there is a machine $T$ which "decides" whether $M(w)$ halts, but we can't compute $T$ from $M$ and $w$, and (2) for any formal system $F$ within which we want to carry out proofs about machines there exists a machine $M$ such that halting of $M$ is undecidable in $F$ (and we can compute $M$ from $F$. It's really the best answer the OP can get, given the question.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I'm confused, in point (1), does it mean that in the canonical halting problem, there is a machine $T$ that can decide whether it halts, only that we can't compute $T$? Because in the canonical halting problem, the machine is always a specific machine, and the input is always its own source code.

Comment: What is the "**canonical** halting problem"? And what does "it" refer to in "there is a machine $T$ that can decide whether **it** halts"?

Comment: @AndrejBauer I wrote an answer, though I'm not sure whether the argument in the second part is legit.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I assume $K = \{(i, x) | \text{program } i \text{ halts when run on input } x\}$ from Wikipedia as canonical. I paraphrased the "it" from your comment, therefore "it" refers to $M(w)$. I totally recognize that $T$ is a different machine from $M$, but still the existence of any machine that could decide the halting problem on any specific machine surprised me. I would like to reconcile that with the common wisdom that the halting problem is undecidable.

Comment: @KennethKho: you're making a basic logical error that is unrelated to Turing machines. Your error is of the following form: the statement "there exists a woman who is the mother of all men" is not true, but the statement "for every man there is a woman who is that man's mother" is true. (Replace "mother" with "program", "man" with "program with a given input" and "is mother of" with "decides the halting of".) Then go read Yuval's answer very carfefully. There is no mystery, just a brain freeze.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I recognize the two sentences are not equivalent. However, even though (A) "every instance of halting problem has a program deciding" is definitely easier than (B) "there exists a program deciding all people instance of halting problem", (A) just still sounds impossible. Every instance has a program deciding, so imagine one specific famous instance, `def g(): if halts(g): loop_forever()`, I can't imagine there's a program that can decide it. As there is a contradiction, I don't think one of the following machines works: The machine that outputs Yes. vs The machine that outputs No.

Comment: `g` is not an instance because it is not valid code. You did not define `halt`. (I can guess that `loop_forever() ` is defined as `def loop_forever(): loop_forever()` or some such, so that bit is unproblematic.)

Comment: What may giving you the feeling of "impossibility" is that *you* might not know which of the two options (the program that says "halts" or the program that says "does not halt") is the correct one. You *must not* think in terms of what "we know" or "can find out" or "we can compute". It's a matter of classical logic that either a machine halts or it does not. In the first case the program that says "Halts" will correctly decide it, and in the second the program that says "Does not halt" will do the job – and it is irrelevant that "we do not know which". Read Yuval's answer.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I see what you mean now. Sentence (A) is technically correct since "it's classical logic that either a machine halts or it does not", but useless at the same time since we can't know which. Sentence (B) is not useless if true but we know it can't be true.

Answer (score 3):

For any specific machine $M_0$ and input $w_0$, there is a machine that decides whether $M_0$ halts on $w_0$. Indeed, one of the following machines works:

- The machine that outputs "Yes".
- The machine that outputs "No".

However, there is no program $P$ that given *arbitrary* $M$ and $w$ produces a machine $T_{M,w}$ that correctly decides whether $M$ halts on $w$, since such a program can be used to solve the halting problem. Indeed, given $M$ and $w$, run $P$ on the input $\langle M,w \rangle$, and then run the machine $T_{M,w}$ that $P$ outputs.

---

We can go further, and for every reasonable proof system $\Pi$ (one for which [Gödel's incompleteness theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems) apply) which is sound and consistent, we can construct a machine $M_\Pi$, accepting no input, such that $\Pi$ cannot "decide" whether $M_\Pi$ halts, in the sense that there is neither proof that $M_\Pi$ halts nor a proof that it doesn't halt. The machine $M_\Pi$ simply enumerates all proofs in $\Pi$, halting if there is a $\Pi$-proof of contradiction. Since $\Pi$ is consistent, $M_\Pi$ doesn't halt, and so, since $\Pi$ is sound, it cannot prove that $M_\Pi$ halts. On the other hand, $\Pi$ cannot prove that $M_\Pi$ doesn't halt, since this contradicts Gödel's second incompleteness theorem.

(I hope that I got this proof right — mathematical logic is often quite confusing.)